# How do you refresh cursors in the algolia index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algolia

Iterating through the index using `browse_from` and cursors, I'm finding that on some pages (usually divisible by 100), there is a warning returned "The cursor is based on an old version of the index."

```
r = index.browse_from({'hitsPerPage':1000,'attributesToRetrieve':['objectID']})
p = res["nbPages"]
this_r = {"cursor": None} # get first page
for i in range(p):
    this_r = index.browse_from({'hitsPerPage':1000,'attributesToRetrieve':['objectID']}, this_r["cursor"])
```

The issue I have is that there would be 1,000 pages, by page 300 it would start using an old cursor, then it would stop shortly after that because there would be a page without a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor of the browse method uses the `objectID` and the position inside the index to list the content. If you perform indexing operation at the same time, you can move or delete the current position of the cursor inside the index.

If the `objectID` is deleted or the internal data structure get optimized by the engine during the browse, the engine will continue the browse in a degraded mode and it'll return a warning message in the response. In that case, some records can be skipped or you can retrieve twice some records depending on the indexing operations.

If you want to perform an exact browse of an index, you'll need to copy it to a temporary index and use the browse method on this index without indexing operations.